# C# to VBConversion

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am converting a control ([Code Project CheckBoxComboBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21085/CheckBox-ComboBox-Extending-the-ComboBox-Class-and)) from C# to VB.  Mostly, I can figure out what the C# is doing and write the equivalent in VB.  I have not been able to figure this piece out, though.

C# Code:

```
if ((Parent as Popup).ProcessResizing(ref m))
```

What is that code trying to do, exactly?  I know it is trying to call the ProcessResizing function in the Popup class, but I am unsure about the `Parent as Popup`.

Comment: `T = X as Y` is kinda equivalent to `try { T = (Y)X; } catch { T = null; }`

Comment: What's with the downvotes?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is the case, but some StackOverflow members are very annoyed by any question associated with language equivalents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`As` operator in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) corresponds to [`TryCast` in VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyy863x8(v=vs.100).aspx). It returns `null` (`Nothing`) if it fails. (`DirectCast` throws an exception in case of failure.)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use [DirectCast Operator (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k6y2h6x.aspx).

```
If DirectCast(Parent, Popup).ProcessResizing(m) = True Then
// ....
End If
```

Comment: It is actually TryCast().  But yeah, no reason to copy a bug :)

Comment: [TryCast is nice when using LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297297/differences-between-vb-trycast-and-c-sharp-as-operator-when-using-linq). According to [Jon Skeet's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385714/why-use-trycast-instead-of-directcast), _If the value really should be a T, then DirectCast is indeed the right way to go..._

Comment: But `DirectCast` will throw if the cast is not valid whereas `TryCast` will just return `Nothing`.  Of course, either way, there will be an exception.  Pick your poison, I suppose.

Comment: This is a decent answer to another question, but not the original question - why is it marked as the answer? (Fratyx's answer is the correct answer).