# What is TryCast and direct cast in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why use TryCast instead of DirectCast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385714/why-use-trycast-instead-of-directcast)

I want to know about `TryCast` and `DirectCast` in VB.NET. What is the difference between them?

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385714/why-use-trycast-instead-of-directcast

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between [`TryCast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyy863x8%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and [`DirectCast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k6y2h6x%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (or [`CType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x2877xb%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)) is that both `CType` and `DirectCast` will throw an [`Exception`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx), specifically an [`InvalidCastException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception.aspx) if the conversion fails.  This is a potentially "expensive" operation.

Conversely, the `TryCast` operator will return `Nothing` if the specified cast fails or cannot be performed, without throwing any exception.  This can be slightly better for performance.

The MSDN articles for `TryCast`, `DirectCast` and `CType` say it best:

> If an attempted conversion fails,
>   `CType` and `DirectCast` both throw an
>   `InvalidCastException` error. This can
>   adversely affect the performance of
>   your application. `TryCast` returns
>   `Nothing` (Visual Basic), so that
>   instead of having to handle a possible
>   exception, you need only test the
>   returned result against Nothing.

and also:

> `DirectCast` does not use the Visual
>   Basic run-time helper routines for
>   conversion, so it can provide somewhat
>   better performance than `CType` when
>   converting to and from data type
>   `Object`.

Comment: That sounds as if you would suggest always use TryCast instead of DirectCast. You should have better pointed out that DirectCast should be used as standard and TryCast only if the cast could fail.

Answer (score 0):

In short:

`TryCast` will return an object set to `Nothing` if the type being cast is not of the type specified.

`DirectCast` will throw an exception if the object type being cast is not of the type specified.

The advantage of `DirectCast` over `TryCast` is `DirectCast` uses less resources and is better for performance.

Code example:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim auto As Car = New Car()
    ' animalItem will be Nothing
    Dim animalItem As Animal = GetAnimal_TypeCast(auto) 

    Dim cat As Cat = New Cat()
    ' animalItem will be Cat as it's of type Animal
    animalItem = GetAnimal_TypeCast(cat)  

    Try
        animalItem = GetAnimal_DirectCast(auto)
    Catch ex As Exception
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Function GetAnimal_TypeCast(ByVal animalType As Object) As Object
    Dim animalBase As Animal

    ' This will produce an object set to Nothing if not of type Animal
    animalBase = TryCast(animalType, Animal)

    Return animalBase

End Function

Private Function GetAnimal_DirectCast(ByVal animalType As Object) As Object
    Dim animalBase As Animal

    ' This will throw an exception if not of type Animal
    animalBase = DirectCast(animalType, Animal)

    Return animalBase

End Function
```